# Import ontology from file (In which the ontology itself imports several other files)

Tags: jena, owl, protege

In Jena I'm loading an ontology into a Model, using this code:

```java
Model model =  FileManager.get().loadModel("/path/myontology.owl");
```

My problem is that "myontology.owl" imports another ontology with `owl:imports`. In pseudo code lets just say  that "Myontology.owl" imports other files to complete the ontology, since several individuals are declared in external files, e.g.:

- In myontology.owl
- Import → myontologywithindividuals.owl

My problem is that I can't import the ontology with its individuals into a single Model in Jena.  That is,

```java
Model model =  FileManager.get().loadModel("/path/myontology.owl");
```

doesn't seem to work. Any idea why? How can I import this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plain models in Jena don't do any processing of `owl:imports`, because plain RDF doesn't have any notion of importing other documents.  Ontology imports are an OWL concept, and you'll need to use an [OntModel](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/ontology/OntModel.html) if you want imports processing.  You may need to use [setDynamicImports()](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/ontology/OntModel.html#setDynamicImports%28boolean%29) to enable import processing.  If the imports statements refer to ontologies using their ontology IRI, but you want to retrieve them from a local file, you may also need to setup the OntModel's [OntDocumentManager](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/ontology/OntModel.html#setDynamicImports%28boolean%29) and [FileManager](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/util/FileManager.html) to take care of the appropriate mapping from IRIs to local files.